# Status bar doesn't change to red one while recording audio

Tags: ios, avfoundation, statusbar

I am using Xcode 4.4 and the iOS 5.1 simulator on Mountain Lion.
I tried to record something with AVAudioRecorder first, and I thought the status bar would change to red, but it didn't.

How can I change color of the status bar to red?

Editing the .plist file didn't help me.

Comment: What edits did you make to the .plist?

Comment: it changes to red when you background the app, not when its in the foreground.

Comment: I edited .plist as below.. 
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>voip</string>
  <string>audio</string>
 </array>

Comment: the status bar doesnt change to red even when i background the app.. and Can't I change it like apple's voice recording utility?

Answer (score 0):

The red bar doesn't show up on the simulator. Only on real devices.